# Создание nav-bar бутстрап

Tags: bootstrap

Пытаюсь создать горизонтальный nav-bar вот код :

```
<div class="container">
<div class="navbar">
  <div class="navbar-inner">
    <a class="brand" href="#">Лого</a>
      <ul class="nav">
      <li class="active"><a href="#">Главная</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Первая</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Вторая</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

результат вот такой https://i.stack.imgur.com/bgVkz.png

Comment: Вы бы полный пример выкладывали, а не картинку как это выглядит.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Исправьте

```
<ul class="nav">
```

на

```
<ul class="nav navbar-nav">
```

Также в Вашем примере отсуствует один закрывающий `</div>`.

Я в таких случаях беру с сайта пример из доков. И просто по одному убираю то, что мне не нужно... (http://getbootstrap.com/components/#navbar)

Comment: http://i.imgur.com/WAjZS0h.png

Comment: Верните `<a class="brand" href="#">Title</a>` внутрь `<ul class="nav navbar-nav">`